# Qual a maneira correta de importar css e javascript na view de um projeto laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Eu vi na internet que coloca os arquivos na pasta public e chama na view a função asset do blade... mas isso está correto atualmente ? por que vejo que no projeto os arquivos js e css vem na pasta resources... 
por padrão... o correto não seria chamar eles de lá ?

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/70).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pasta `public` é, como o próprio nome diz, pública, ou seja, tudo que ela contiver é acessível via url do servidor que está rodando a aplicação. Exemplo se sua aplicação estiver rodando no localhost na porta 80:

`SUA_APLICACAO/app/public/img/logo.png`

estará disponível via: `http://localhost/img/logo.png`.

Agora, se mover este mesmo arquivo para a pasta `resources` ele não estará mais disponível na url acima.

Já a pasta `resources` ficam os arquivos que fonte do front-end que poderão ser compilados  e seus resultados irão para a `public`.

Não necessariamente a função `asset()` (que é um helper e pode ser acessado em qualquer lugar da aplicação, não só no Blade) irá buscar os arquivos na `public`, seus arquivos podem estar em outro lugar como no exemplo da documentação:
https://laravel.com/docs/master/helpers#method-asset